# jquery: appending a [object Object] to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Jquery can't seem to turn the type of **str2** into a string, no matter what i tried.

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
      $(xml).find("product").each(function()
      {

           var str1 = "div.timer";
           var **str2** = $(this).find("id");


           $("div.timer17").html(str1 + str2);
      });
}
```

Every time this function is ran, content of div.timer17 changes to **div.timer[object Object]**.

I tried turning the object Object into a string with new String(obj), with json.stringify, etc. Nothing worked. Please help.

My goal is appending str2 to str1, so i can get the wanted selector (for example, div.timer25).

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
<product cookie="The red">
  <timediff>02:28:59</timediff>
  <username>denis</username>
  <price>25</price>
  <id>17</id>
</product>

<product cookie="The red">
  <timediff>00:28:59</timediff>
  <username>denis</username>
  <price>35</price>
  <id>18</id>
</product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the `text` or `html` I think you want this

```
var str2 = $(this).find("id").text();
```

or

```
var str2 = $(this).find("id").html();
```

Comment: Fixed it... god I can't beleive i spent so much time on this. Thanks.

Comment: No worries...I'm at the same point with something else so I thought I feel better by trying to help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find("id")` returns an object, this is why it's printing `[object Object]`.  It's a jQuery object, and it can't just be turned into a string, because what should that print out?

If you want the text from the node, try this:

```
var str2 = $(this).find("id").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable str2 is a jQuery objecy, it is not a string. Are you looking for the id attribute of the XML node being iterated?

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).find("product").each(function() {    
    var str1 = "div.timer";
    var str2 = this.id;
    $("div.timer17").html(str1 + str2);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe once you each find "product" you can use them as an object and just call something like $(this).id.

$(xml).find("product").each(function()
  {

```
   var str1 = "div.timer";
   var **str2** = $(this).id;


   $("div.timer17").html(str1 + str2);
```

});

If your using firefox and firebug, place the Object in console.info(someobject); it will usually string out the object.

Comment: Its either $this0.id or this.id.